# How to restore a EC public key from public bytes or public numbers in python (cryptography module)

Tags: python, ssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to send a public key to a remote peer in order to calculate a shared key.
I'm using python's `cryptography` module, and I'm using `ec` not `rsa`.

I can send over the public numbers:

```
value = ecdh_public_key.public_numbers()
```

or the public bytes:

```
value = ecdh_public_key.public_bytes()
```

but in both cases I don't know how to convert them back into an ec public key object in the other side.

The whole code:

```
# Generating ECDH private/public key
ecdh_private_key = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP256R1(), default_backend())
ecdh_public_key = ecdh_private_key.public_key()

# exchange public keys
value = ecdh_public_key.public_numbers()
```

EDIT:
The value I get after using `public_bytes()` is PKCS1 key. So if there's a way I can convert a PKCS1 key to a public key object it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
By importing `load_pem_public_key` method like this:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_public_key
```

then use it to create a public key object from public bytes:

```
public_key = load_pem_public_key(remote_public_bytes, default_backend())
```